# Google Adwords API with OAuth2 how to obtain authorised user's email?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-ads-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement managed accounts using Google's Adwords API SDK in Ruby within a Rails app.

The user flow is like this:

1. User clicks on Login with Google Account
2. User authorises my app to use Google Account info
3. User then can retrieve a list of Managed Adword Accounts

I've looked at the Adwords API documentation, and looking through Stackoverflow it looks like you can't retrieve the current logged in user's name and email through a method call on the Adwords API. So I'm wondering, if this needs to be exposed or passed along in the token when I first authorise my app to use my Google account?

Facebook's Ads API makes this easy, you can get the user associated with the token by calling `/me`.

I was wondering if theres a straightforward way to do the same with Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite similar for Google, you can use the [`people.get`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) end point at

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

For that to work however, you'll need an access token that has at least the `email` scope (or [`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#oauth2v2), which is equivalent).